# OpenMP: error: ‘w.13’ not specified in enclosing parallel

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

I am trying to use OpenMP to parallelize a simple program simulating Game of Life.

I have the following function:

```
void evolve_parallel(void *u, int w, int h)
{
    unsigned (*univ)[w] = u;
    unsigned new[h][w];

    #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(univ, new, w, h), collapse(2), default(none)
    for_y for_x {
        int n = 0;
        for (int y1 = y - 1; y1 <= y + 1; y1++)
            for (int x1 = x - 1; x1 <= x + 1; x1++)
                if (univ[(y1 + h) % h][(x1 + w) % w])
                    n++;

        if (univ[y][x]) n--;
        new[y][x] = (n == 3 || (n == 2 && univ[y][x]));
    }
    for_y for_x univ[y][x] = new[y][x];
}
```

My macros (at the top of the file) are:

```
#define for_x for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
#define for_y for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
#define for_xy for_x for_y
```

I am compiling it with `gcc-4.8 gameoflife.c -o gameoflife -std=gnu99 -O3 -fopenmp`, on bash on Windows 10, and gcc gives me the following error:

```
gameoflife.c: In function ‘evolve_parallel’:
gameoflife.c:131:13: error: ‘w.13’ not specified in enclosing parallel
     if (univ[(y1 + h) % h][(x1 + w) % w])
             ^
gameoflife.c:126:10: error: enclosing parallel
  #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(univ, new, w, h), collapse(2), default(none)
          ^
```

If I remove the `default(none)`, the code compiles, but I want to keep it so that when I continue changing the code, the compiler would alert me if I forget to declare some variables private or firstprivate.

Obviously, I do not have a variable called `w.13`, and that isn't some external variable that I am using. Does anybody know why my code isn't compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in gcc, and it's still present in the latest version (7.2).

What I suspect happens here is that the *variably modified* (pointer to *variable length array*) type uses a hidden variable `w.13` that is implicitly accessed whenever univ is accessed. In a sense the compiler thinks about this code like:

```
// instead of unsigned (*univ)[w] ...;
unsigned **univ ...;
const int w.13 = w;
....
// instead of univ[x][y]
univ[x * w.13 + y]
```

A shorter version to reproduce:

```
void foo(int n, int a[][n])
{
    #pragma omp parallel shared(a) default(none)
    a[23][0] = 42;
}
```

Feel free to report a bug, or I will do so.
I suppose you got to drop the `default(none)`. Alternatively you can use something other than a *variably modified*. I for myself am not a big fan of them.

That said there are some other issues in your code. You most likely do not want to use `firstprivate` on all those variables, but `shared` instead. If something is only read during the parallel region, which is the case for `univ, w, h`, then it can safely and should be `shared`. `new` is the result of the parallel region and should thus also be shared. The contents of `private` (and `firstprivate`) variables are not preserved after a parallel region. It's also safe for `new` to be shared, because each iteration (and thus thread) accesses a separate element.

For performance reasons you should revert the order of the loops. This will produce contiguous memory accesses (at least to `new`) which helps the serial case but especially the parallel case to avoid false sharing.

And finally, if you like to keep your sanity: **drop the macros**. The level of pain and confusion they will inflict on you is many orders of magnitude larger than the little bit of convenience they provide. I guarantee that - I promise you even get your money back if I was wrong.

Note: I couldn't find any reference to such types in the OpenMP standard, although the standard does reference C99.

Comment: It was shared at first, but then, when I saw the compiler error, I tried with firstprivate and forgot to change back to shared. I will change it back, thanks.

About the performance issues - I think that the order of loops is OK, because new is accessed as `new[y][x]`, so the first loop should be over y, and the second over x.

And last, this is not my code, I am just parallelizing it, so the macros are what I got in the first place.

Comment: @Zulan, thank you for the answer! Would it be too much to ask you to report that bug? I came here by chance while looking for `‘._94’ not specified in enclosing parallel` (with no VLAs in my code, either).

Comment: @aitap https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85696 - if you have no VLA it may be broader issue, so feel free to post your minimal example in the bug or as another question on SO.

Comment: @Zulan: Thanks! I played around some more and realized that my bug had been fixed in 8.1: https://godbolt.org/g/UvqdpJ